# Register external javascript file within a Codeigniter view for adding to the <head> when outputting the page?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, include

Is it possible when creating a [view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) in [Codeigniter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeigniter#CodeIgniter) to use a command to register an external Javascript file to be included in the `<head>` when the final output is written?

I have a main view which contains many smaller sub-views (sidebar, adverts, other controls, etc). inside one or more of these smaller views i want to incorporate some javascript functionality. To keep things modular i would like to 'include' that Javascript inside the smaller sub-views (without actually writing it to the html page at that sub-view's position (i want it in the head)). Is this possible?

Comment: Do you have a dedicated view just for your <head>?

Comment: The actual head tags are in the main view but there is a separate sub-view for some head content.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help you, CodeIgniter's javascript class, http://codeigniter.local/user_guide/libraries/javascript.html.

Comment: In my case, I would put a condition in the main view or in a separate sub-view that would return true (and then register the external Javascript file) if one of my modules need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up overiding and implementing my own `Output` class. (Placed in the 'application/core/' folder)

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Output extends CI_Output
{
    private $JavascriptFiles = array();
    private $JavascriptTags = "";

    private $CSSFiles = array();
    private $CSSTags = "";

    //Add a javascript file to the array.
    public function javascript($File = null)
    {
        if($File && !in_array($File ,$this->JavascriptFiles))
        {
            $this->JavascriptFiles[] = $File;
        }
    }

    //Add a css file to the array.
    public function css($File = null)
    {
        if($File && !in_array($File ,$this->CSSFiles))
        {
            $this->CSSFiles[] = $File;
        }
    }

    //Build the javascript tags
    private function buildtags()
    {
        if(!empty($this->JavascriptFiles))
        {
            foreach($this->JavascriptFiles as $File) {
                $this->JavascriptTags .= "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"$File\"></script>\n";
            }
        }

        if(!empty($this->CSSFiles))
        {
            foreach($this->CSSFiles as $File) {
                $this->CSSTags .= "<link type=\"text/css\" href=\"$File\" rel=\"stylesheet\" media=\"all\" />\n";
            }
        }
    }


    //Override the main output function that sends content to the browser
    //and slap in the javascript and css where we need it.
    function _display($output = '')
    {

        $this->buildtags();
        $this->final_output = str_replace("{VIEW_SPECIFIC_JAVASCRIPT}", $this->JavascriptTags, $this->final_output);
        $this->final_output = str_replace("{VIEW_SPECIFIC_CSS}", $this->CSSTags, $this->final_output);

        // SNIP----
        // Rest of method code follows from here
}
```

I added the tags `{VIEW_SPECIFIC_JAVASCRIPT}` and `{VIEW_SPECIFIC_CSS}` into my `<head>` view at the appropriate places.

Then i can add javascript and css into the `<head>` from any view in my application by using the following methods inside the views:

```
$this->output->javascript("/js/mycoolscript.js");
$this->output->css("/js/mycoolcss.js");
```

Simple.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the template library? http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/

It allows use to include JavaScript either in the head on a controller basis or inline.

```
$this->template->add_js('js/jquery.js');
```